# rotating BufferedImage with efficient angle in java

Tags: java, image, image-processing

I want to rotate a BufferedImage from a math phrase so that become like this :

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ekP77.jpg

convert to :

https://i.stack.imgur.com/tYth1.jpg

we have not images and them include by user.

Answer (score 1):

Minimize axis aligned bounding box area.

Simplest algorithm could do coarse estimation every 10 degrees. Pick best angle and do refinement with smaller angular step.

Probably you should pick wider rather than taller result.